# Windows 10 IIS ASP.NET/.NET Framework Issue

Tags: asp.net, iis

I recently ran this command `aspnet_regiis.exe -iru` in the path \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 to register IIS with asp.net to get our WCF services running however I am now getting an error trying to load up the home page. Note: The homepage was running before executing that command. This is the error messge:

Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I have tried to run that command again however it says:

Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

Our website is using the .net framework 4.5 and these are the options ticked in add new features section:

[IIS/ASP.Net settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0snO.png)

Can anyone shed some light on how I go about fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe if you try to uninstall and install again the IIS and asp.net and all that relative modules from the windows features dialog

Comment: aspnet_regiis is for ASP.NET. For WCF you need to run ServiceModelReg.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!